# Questions about the complex proof of the fundamental thm of algebra.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus

Here is the question I am trying to prove (I am very new to complex analysis):

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and take $R > 0$ so large that the circle $\gamma(t) = R e^{it}, 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi,$ encloses all the zeros of $p$ in its interior. Prove that $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz = 2 \pi n i$$

I do not know a clean and simple way of proving this. I have some questions:

1- what should be the most logic and intuitive steps of the solution?

2- can the polynomial have degree 0?

3- What is the importance of $\gamma$ encloses all the zeros of $p$ in its interior?

4- Why any complex polynomial is analytic?

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "What is the essence of the idea of the proof?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: Have you studied differential forms? Irrelevant to this, but can sort of give you some intuition as to why the assumptions are necessary and why it makes sense, for start.

Comment: @jjagmath corrected ... so sorry about that

Comment: *"Why any complex polynomial is analytic?"* Analytic means the function has a power series that converges in some open ball for each point in the domain-- a polynomial function has finitely many terms in said power series so of course it converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Question 1* : In fact $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}$ is the **logarithmic derivative** of polynomial $p$, and can be expressed in the following way:

$$\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\frac{1}{z-r_1}+\frac{1}{z-r_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{z-r_n},$$

where $r_1,r_2,\cdots r_n$ are the roots of $p$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518758/305862)).

For each of these zeros $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z-r_k}=2 \pi i$ (for example by applying residue theorem, or plainly Cauchy formula with $f(z)=1$). Now make the summation $n$ times.

*Question 2*: Yes, in the case $n=0$, your formula is reduced to $0=0$, hence valid.

*Question 3*: If one of the roots $r_k$ is outside $\gamma$, the residue theorem will give $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z-r_k}=0$ instead of $2 \pi i$.

*Question 4*: "analytic" is synonymous to "holomorphic", meaning "differentiable function of the complex variable", which is the case for a polynomial.